# Using scipy's minimizer with multiple constraints

Tags: python, scipy, minimize

I am stuck with an 'easy' model for my master's thesis. I want to decompose a vector into chunks,  whose added values should be as near as possible. I wrote an objective function, which takes the big vector and an index vector and computes the standard deviaton for my chunks.
I then give it to scipy's minimize routine but I don't understand if (and then how) it's possible to tell minimize, that my values have to be ascending (I at leas managed it to keep them in given bounds), since they are indices.

Standard deviation before optimization is 39, afterwards I get 1882. I think I didn't really understand how this minimizer works.

Since I didn't hear any lectures about discrete optimization I have no idea how to tackle this problem properly. Is there an algorithm to minimize a function from N^n to R? I'd love some advice and I hope it's okay to post my code here.

```
import numpy as np
import statistics as stat
from scipy.optimize import minimize


# define objective function to minimize
# returns standard deviation of the distributed computational effort
def distribution_deviation(cell_list_vec, index_vec):
    # initialize computational loads for every chunk
    loads = np.zeros(index_vec.size + 1)
    index_vec = np.insert(index_vec, 0, 0)
    index_vec = np.append(index_vec, cell_list_vec.size - 1)
    index_vec = index_vec.astype(int)
    for i in range(index_vec.size - 1):
        loads[i] = np.sum(cell_list_vec[index_vec[i]:index_vec[i+1]])
    return stat.stdev(loads)


np.random.seed(123)  # set random seed for reproducibility
# initialize array with random numbers between 0 and 100 (representing cells and their computational cost)
n_cells = 100  # number of cells
n_chunks = 5  # number of chunks/ processors
cell_list = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=100, size=n_cells)
# index vector for chunks
index = np.linspace(start=0, stop=cell_list.size, num=n_chunks + 1)  # linear spaced
index = index[1:n_chunks]  # remove endpoints
index = index.astype(int)  # cast to integer


# test objective function
dev = distribution_deviation(cell_list, index)

print("Index vector before optimization (without endpoints):")
print(index)
print("Inter chunk standard deviation: " + str(dev))
print("Start optimization...")

# use optimizer here
# initialize bounds
bound_sequence = []
for i in range(index.size):
    bound_sequence += [(0, cell_list.size)]

# these can handle bounds:
# L-BFGS-B, TNC, SLSQP
index_res = minimize(distribution_deviation, x0=index, args=cell_list, method='SLSQP', bounds=bound_sequence)
# get array from solution object
index_res = index_res.x
# construct index vector
index_res = np.insert(index_res, 0, 0)
index_res = np.append(index_res, cell_list.size - 1)
index_res = index_res.astype(int)
print("Index vector after optimization:")
print(index_res) # cast result

dev = distribution_deviation(cell_list, index_res)
print("Inter chunk deviation after optimization: " + str(dev))
```

Comment: And all the "chunks" are contiguous? That is, it's not possible for a chunk to contain something from the beginning of the vector, nothing from the middle, and something from the end?

Comment: And is your input representative? I.e. can one assume that you have a 100-dimensional vector and you need 4 indices?

Comment: The chunks have to be contiguous, yes. The input vector represents processes (cells of a discretization in a PDE solver) of a numerical simulation, that is to be executed on a HPC cluster. I want to distribute the computational cost as good as possible and it makes a difference whether cells are connected or not.
The 100 and 4 are quite arbitrary. The input length corresponds to the number of cells in the computational domain and the number of chunks corresponds to the number of processors/ sockets available.

Comment: The reason for asking about the numbers is that for the (100, 4) case, a relatively simple algorithm could probably give you the answer in a reasonable amount of time: You could brute force the relevant search space and probably add a bit of pruning to get rid of the extreme cases (e.g. by calculating bounds on means as you move along and prune when a chunk's sum deviates enough from the mean), but this will scale poorly with respect to the number of chunks, so it becomes important to understand how large the relevant inputs are.

Comment: And to answer the question you added between the lines: When you're only dealing with a finite subset of ℕ^n, then yes, brute forcing would be an example of such an algorithm. If not, then no: The unsolvability of Hilbert's tenth problem provides an example that in full generality, the general minimization problem you've posed is undecidable.

Comment: The final application would deal with somethin like (1e9, 1e4) (in extreme cases) but the final goal is to apply some ML techniques to solve this problem. This is supposed to be something like a benchmark problem to test further methods against.
So I got it right that I have to solve this problem by brute force?

Comment: If you want to use ML techniques, does this mean that the elements of the vector have additional structure that is not covered by the question as is? If so, an algorithm might well be able to make use of that as well. And no, you can use brute force and that will definitely give you the optimal solution, but you can probably do better by pruning early, e.g. by calculating bounds on your means as you move along. I imagine you can also hunt for optimal substructure and use dynamic programming to your advantage.

Comment: To be honest I don't have an idea how to implement the ML stuff yet. The final application will be dynamic load balancing for an HPC application. In this case, I will have more structure but won't know the computational cost.
I wanted to solve this problem, then build a model with more structure und go to the final thing step by step. 
In the end I'll only know which processes ran on a processor and the time the processor actually did something. This should be (somehow) the same problem as now, but the long input vector's values won't be visible to the minimizer.

Comment: I think this is related to the problem described [here](https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2018/02/on-scheduling-of-reading-book-chapters.html)